# Prevent MySQL Duplicate Insert in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import different user lists to different tables in a mysql database. 
Sample table structure:

uid  |  uname   | email |

the uid field in any table should not have a duplicate value in it. What is the easiest way to achieve this? Any help?

Comment: Why not stuff them all in the same table and make `uid` a primary key?

Comment: have you tried looking this up? i think google would be a good friend for you

Comment: @esqew, I need separate tables.

Comment: @AbhijithSJ As answerers below have said, if you need multiple tables with data structured the same way, you have a modeling issue.

Comment: @AbhijithSJ: I really doubt that you *need* separate tables.  It's more likely that you *already have* separate tables and don't want to change that.

Comment: Its my client's decision to keep it in different tables since each list belongs to different backend users.

Comment: @AbhijithSJ: Fair enough that it isn't *your* decision, but it's still the wrong decision.  I hope you at least strongly advised the client accordingly.  They're far from being the first client to have this idea, they're simply the latest in a long history of clients who don't know how to model data.  (That's why they hire us, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an incorrect data model.  It's highly likely that these records should be in *one* table, not many.  (Though there could be information you haven't shared which justifies your approach, I *really* doubt it.)

One idea which may help you would be to extract the identifier into a common parent table from which your other tables "inherit" identifiers.  For example, you might have a parent table like this:

```
BaseUser
--------
uid (int, PK)
etc.
```

Then other types of user tables might look like this:

```
DerivedUser
--------
uid (int, PK, FK to BaseUser.id)
etc.
```

If all of the "derived" tables have their `uid` column as a foreign key to the `BaseUser` table's `uid` column then they all make use of that centralized unique enforcement.  I *believe* this is called "supertyping" tables.  Conceptually this is designing the data model such that the *identifier* for a set of otherwise unrelated records is separate from the *details* of those records (and, thus, originated in a separate table).